# Область видимости в Pascal, Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, form, lazarus

Задали форму составить, на ней должны быть две кнопки, два эдита для ввода данных и лэйбл для вывода. Первая кнопка считает сумму двух значения эдитов, а вторая кнопка выводит эту сумму на лэйбл. Как сделать так, чтобы сумма могла передаться из одной функции на другую? Без использования глобальных переменных. Нам сказали, что если создать некую псевдофункцию, то можно будет каким-то образом изменить область видимости переменной, которая содержит в себе сумму. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нам сказали, что если создать некую псевдофункцию, то можно будет каким-то образом изменить область видимости переменной, которая содержит в себе сумму.

Видимо, имелся в виду доступ к переменной через `Get`/`Set` методы:

```
type
  TFooObj = class
  private
    FSum: Int64;
    function GetSum: Int64;
    procedure SetSum(const AValue: Int64);
  public
    property Sum: Int64 read GetSum write SetSum;
  end;

{ TFooObj }

function TFooObj.GetSum: Int64;
begin
  Result := FSum;
end;

procedure TFooObj.SetSum(const AValue: Int64);
begin
  FSum := AValue;
end;
```

Переменная `FSum` является приватной, т.е. область видимости ограничена классом, в котором она объявлена и снаружи эта переменная не видна. Однако, можно изменить/получить её значение, но только через специальные функции.

Это делается для того, чтобы полностью контролировать доступ к данным и не выставлять наружу лишнего (инкапсуляция).

Конечно, заводить целый класс для доступа к одной переменной бессмысленно, но если, к примеру, сделать из этого класса некий `TCalculator` с методами `SetOperandA` и `SetOperandB`, которые будут запоминать операнды в приватных переменных, то можно будет написать несколько методов вроде `GetSum`, `GetDiff` (разность), `GetMulti` (умножение) и т.д. в которых выполнять реальные вычисления над заданными операндами. Естественно, результат операций уже хранить не нужно, а просто вычислять по запросу, ну и методов для установки значений (вроде `SetSum`) не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Создать поле класса и в него записывать

```delphi
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Edit1: TEdit;
  Edit2: TEdit;
  Label1: TLabel;
  Button1: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
private
  FSum: Integer;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSum := StrToInt(Edit1.Text) + StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(FSum);
end;
```

Comment: А чем это отличается от глобальных переменных?

Comment: Это глобальная переменная, получается.

Comment: Тем, что глобальная переменная имеет ровно один экземпляр, а поле класса свое для каждого объекта. Кроме того поле с модификатором `private` видно только в том модуле, где объявлен класс. А в новых Delphi можно использовать модификатор `strict private` и тогда оно будет видно только в пределах одного класса